# Celery doesn't see the redis broker

Tags: python, redis, celery, messagebroker, broker

I am trying to use Celery with Redis.

It is my **celery.py** file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery

celery=Celery(include=[ 'tasks.chatterbox' ])

# import celery config file
celery.config_from_object('celeryconfig')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    celery.start()
```

It is my **celeryconfig.py** file:

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

# redis backend
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://'
```

And when I run:

```
celery -A broker.celery worker -l info
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('celery==3.1.11', 'console_scripts', 'celery')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.11-py2.7.egg/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.11-py2.7.egg/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.11-py2.7.egg/celery/bin/celery.py", line 769, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.11-py2.7.egg/celery/bin/base.py", line 306, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.11-py2.7.egg/celery/bin/celery.py", line 761, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.11-py2.7.egg/celery/bin/celery.py", line 693, in execute
    ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.11-py2.7.egg/celery/bin/worker.py", line 179, in run_from_argv
    return self(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.11-py2.7.egg/celery/bin/base.py", line 269, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.11-py2.7.egg/celery/bin/worker.py", line 212, in run
    state_db=self.node_format(state_db, hostname), **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.11-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/__init__.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.setup_instance(**self.prepare_args(**kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.11-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/__init__.py", line 126, in setup_instance
    self.should_use_eventloop() if use_eventloop is None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.11-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/__init__.py", line 245, in should_use_eventloop
    self._conninfo.is_evented and not self.app.IS_WINDOWS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu-3.0.16-py2.7.egg/kombu/connection.py", line 836, in is_evented
    return self.transport.supports_ev
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu-3.0.16-py2.7.egg/kombu/connection.py", line 786, in transport
    self._transport = self.create_transport()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu-3.0.16-py2.7.egg/kombu/connection.py", line 518, in create_transport
    return self.get_transport_cls()(client=self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu-3.0.16-py2.7.egg/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 916, in __init__
    self.connection_errors, self.channel_errors = self._get_errors()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu-3.0.16-py2.7.egg/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 954, in _get_errors
    return get_redis_error_classes()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu-3.0.16-py2.7.egg/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 78, in get_redis_error_classes
    from redis import exceptions
ImportError: No module named redis
```

Finally, it is my project structure:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── celeryconfig.py
├── broker
│   ├── celery.py
│   ├── __init__.py    
├── tasks
    ├── chatterbox.py
    ├── __init__.py
```

I am using:

- Celery 3.1.11
- Redis 2.8.8

Comment: Try installing the Python redis library: `pip install redis`

Comment: I made the project with rabbitmq, but I changed to redis, and then I got this error. Maybe I missed something in the configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error trace states the cause clearly (as usual, reading it bottom up)

```
ImportError: No module named redis
```

You can check, if `redis` is installed

Using `pip`

```
$ pip freeze
```

The output shall contain a line starting with `redis=`

Install redis:

```
$ pip install redis
```

I use `virtualenv` and sometime forget to switch to proper environment. In those cases I miss the module I expect to be present. Then I simply switch to proper virtual env or install the missing module.

PS: Basic trick for becoming an expert is reading error messages and following it.

Comment: I am sorry, I thought that with redis-server installed was enought. Tanks

Comment: @Rob3 Your expectation (that Python `redis` will get installed by server installation) was exactly the same as my initial one. It seems like favourite mistake.

Comment: I hit this problem and just needed a new terminal after installing. When in doubt, turn it off and back on again

Answer (score 2):

You can install both Celery and Redis (python) dependencies in one go using the celery[redis] bundle

```
$ pip install -U celery[redis]
```

References

- [Celery - using Redis as Broker](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html#installation)
- [Available Celery bundles](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/introduction.html#bundles)

Comment: The link to available celery bundles is extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and fixed it by installing redis with python3. Sometimes, your system defaults to using python2 if you don't specify. In your command line or terminal, type in

```
python3 -m pip install redis
```

That should download redis in Python3 for you, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

[FOR Django users only]

```
ImportError: Missing redis library
```

This error could happen because Celery uses ENVs first before Django settings to initiate itself.

For example if you have **Django settings** like `CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672/` and for some reason, your **ENVs** contain `CELERY_BROKER_URL` or `BROKER_URL` with `redis` - celery will use `redis broker` from envs.